# Función en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Con el siguiente código en SQL Server, me tira este error:

> Mens 156, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento DiasFeriados, Línea 15
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'END'

en el ante ultimo END. Me podrían ayudar a encontrar cual es el error?. Gracias.

```
 USE BASE
go  
create function DiasFeriados
--Funciòn para identificar si existen dias feriados entre la fecha ingresada y el dia actual.
(@FechaInicial datetime)
returns int
as
begin 
    DECLARE @Cantidad INT = 0;
    WHILE (@FechaInicial <= GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        IF @FechaInicial IN (SELECT Fecha FROM BASE.dbo.CalendarioFechasEspeciales)
        BEGIN
            SET @Cantidad = @Cantidad + 1
        END
        SET @FechaInicial = (DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaInicial)
     END<---- Aca me marca el error. 
   return @Cantidad;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque se te olvidó cerrar un paréntesis en

```
    SET @FechaInicial = (DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaInicial))
```

O puedes quitar el paréntesis inicial

```
    SET @FechaInicial = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaInicial)
```

Sin embargo, ya que estamos viendo la función, te recomiendo evitar este tipo de código y cambiar a lógica de conjuntos. Esto va más acorde a la lógica de bases de datos, pero la razón principal es que mejorará el rendimiento y optimizará las consultas de una manera colosal.

Así puedes crear una función tipo tabla que te regrese el resultado que deseas.

```
create function DiasFeriados
--Funciòn para identificar si existen dias feriados entre la fecha ingresada y el dia actual.
(@FechaInicial datetime)
returns table
as
RETURN
SELECT COUNT(*) AS diasferiados
FROM BASE.dbo.CalendarioFechasEspeciales
WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND GETDATE();
```

Luego sólo tienes que aprender a llamarla de forma correcta

```
SELECT *
FROM TuTabla
CROSS APPLY dbo.DiasFeriados( Fecha) x;
```

Comment: Excelente, te agradezco por los consejos.

Comment: disculpa que te moleste pero te quería realizar una consulta. El ejemplo que me pusiste me da error en el nombre de la función. Donde pone que no se especifico ningún nombre de columna para la columna 1. Te pido disculpas por si es una pregunta muy simple, pero no pude encontrar teoría para resolverlo solo. Aguardo por tu respuesta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No me había fijado. Es porque las columnas devueltas por la función deben tener un nombre o alias y se me olvidó asignarlo. Acabo de editar el código original para que aparezca.

Comment: Excelente era justamente lo que decías muchas gracias. Sabes alguna fuente donde leer teoría sobre la Lógica de conjunto aplicada en SQL Server.

Comment: No estoy seguro. Gran parte lo aprendí de los artículos de SqlServerCentral.com Lo más importante que debes recordar es "dejar de pensar que quieres hacer con una fila, en su lugar piensa que quieres hacer con una columna".

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Esa consulta no tienen ningún error. A menos, de que estés apuntando a una tabla o base de datos incorrecta.

Comment: La ejecuto tal cual la puse y  siempre me da cero, sin importan la fecha inicial que le ponga. La tabla CalendariosFechasEspeciales. contiene los feriados de este año, con la fecha ingresada con el tipo DATE en la columna FECHA.

Comment: Te parece si continuamos con el problema en el chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93623/funcion-en-sql-server-contar-dias-feriados

Comment: Por lo que veo no puedo escribir en el chat, ya que al ser una cuenta reciente no me alcanzan los puntos de reputación.

Comment: Te acabo de dar acceso a ese chat

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, fue error mio. 
Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió de mucho!.